# How do I remove particular files from dir_ls?

Tags: r, directory, tidyverse

I have a wide number of .csv data files in a "RawData" folder, some of which are simply test runs which I want to ignore when importing. These files are easily identifiable outside of R, and I could easily just manually delete them. However, I want my entire analysis process to be transparent and replicable to others; they will download these useless data files (along with real data files) directly from the source, and will be able to see which files I'm excluding and why.

My question is: how do I edit my `dir_ls` result so that explicitly named files are ignored? Example: if the result of `dir_ls` is "file1", "file2", "file3", "file4", "file5", how can I edit that list to "file1", "file3", "file4". I have ~400 data files, so I can't simply name the files I want.

```
data_dir <- "RawData/"              # Set main directory of data files. 
csv_file_list <- data_dir %>%       # For data directory...
  dir_ls(regexp = "\\.csv$")        # List all files that end with '.csv'...
  ** remove these file names: c("file_2", "file_4") from csv_file_list **

raw_data <- map_dfr(csv_file_list, ~read_csv(.x, col_types = cols(.default = "c")))
```

Any help appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setdiff` to remove specific elements from a character vector

```
setdiff(csv_file_list, paste0('file_', c(2, 4), '.csv'))
```

Or `grep` to remove elements containing a specific pattern

```
grep('^file_2|^file_4', csv_file_list, invert = TRUE, value = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

With `dir_ls`, you can use `invert=TRUE` which *excludes* files matched by `regexp` – solution for the provided example:

```
dir_ls(datadir, regexp = "(file2|file4)\\.csv", invert = TRUE)
```